# What is the meaning of an "eye" system icon on Samsung devices?

Tags: samsung, notification-icons

This is a Samsung device showing an "eye" system icon on the notification bar.

[image]

What does it mean?

Comment: Samsung Smart Stay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, it is the Samsung feature which keeps the display turned on for as long as you're looking at it. This is helpful if you're reading something off the display and don't want it to sleep.

The setting/feature can be disabled in Display Settings of the phone.

Comment: thanks, does this mean that display knows when u look at it and when not? and how is this possible? what technology is used?

Comment: AFAIK, it's just the front cam looking at your face and figuring out if you're looking at it or not. Samsung explained a bit here - https://www.samsung.com/uk/support/mobile-devices/what-is-the-smart-stay-feature-on-my-samsung-galaxy-s4/